# UIImageview’s Image For Constant Height

Tags: ios, iphone

I have a query regarding image resolution in different iPhone devices.

In my app, I have imageview of constant height(125 px) but width varies as per device width. Imageview content mode is Aspect Fit

I created images with following sizes
1. myLogo.png (320x125 px)
2. myLogo@2x.png (640x250 px)
3. myLogo@3x.png (960x375 px)

After adding image in my imageview, I can see that images are not getting fit in different devices .

If I make imageview content mode to aspectfill, then images are getting stretch.

So pleas suggest or guide me how to handle images in different devices with constant height & varying width.

Please let me know if I have to explain my question.

Answer (score 1):

That's expected. If height is a constant, then you can't expect the image's width to be stretched while maintaining aspect ratio.

The solution would be for height to not be constant, but rely on width with a multiplier:

```
imageView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: imageView.widthAnchor, multiplier: 125.0/320.0, constant: 0).isActive = true
```

Answer (score 1):

Set the image view's internal constraints using the Aspect Ratio setting. Now set its external constraints the way you want them. The image view can now grow and shrink to fit the screen, as you desire, but it will always have the correct proportions.

By the way, this has *nothing* to do with the initial premise of your question, i.e. the existence of different variants for different screen resolutions. This is about screen size, not resolution.